# Selenium, webdriver - can't find - xpath/css_selector/... python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, checkbox, webdriver

Somebody can upload code of clicking the checkbox in this page **IN PYTHON ONLY**- https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

i cant find the xpath for this code ...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver1 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver1.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
driver1.find_element_by_xpath(...).click()
```

if it wasn't clear, i want to click this button ( in the circle )

[image]

Comment: `can't find - xpath/css_selector` for which WebElement/field ?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: click on the checkbox in the page

Comment: here try this https://github.com/matty120/I-m-Not-A-Robot-Clicker

Answer (score 2):

The xpath is `//*[@class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark"]`

The checkbox is inside iframe first you need to switch to the frame then you can find element and click.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver1 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver1.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
driver1.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe'))
driver1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark"]').click()
```

I have tried with java and it is able to click on the checkbox, the java code is given below.

```
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo");
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
new WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.className("recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark")))).click();
```

Comment: seconde, can you explain me how u found it?

Comment: when i inspect using chrome it takes me to the element and then i used classname of it. I am able to do it.

Comment: yea but how you know that you have to change frame and the name of the frame?

Comment: i understand how you find the class name but not how you knew that you need to switch frame and what is the name of the frame

Comment: when i tried with class name , i got element not found exception. later i checked,  inside frame or not. then i used switch to element. if element is not found then, mainly two reasons. 1. we are not giving correct locator or element is not on the page 2. it may be inside the iframe.

Comment: I just searched for iframe tag on entire page source. then checked the element which we want is inside iframe tag or not.

Comment: Yes the element recaptcha-audio-button is inside frame also, it is disabled i guess,may be you are not able to interact with it. please accept my answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Switching to iFrames catches a lot of people out, but if you have content that is loaded from a different domain (in this case the Captcha) then you need to switch to that with

```
driver.switchTo().frame(<integer of frame or id>);
```

Then you will be be able to interact the selector of your choice.